# Django: return form data on the same page

Tags: python, django

How can I add "headers" to context so it's accessible in templates. I guess it needs to be pass to get request somehow? What would be the pythonic way to pass this variable to a get method in FormView class?

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = CheckForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['headers'] = form.result()
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="." method="post" name="url" id="url" novalidate>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Check</button>

{% if headers %}
{% for k,v in headers %}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<br>No data
{% endif %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

import requests

class CheckForm(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=255, label='')

    def result(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        url = cd['url']
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.headers
        return r
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Have you tried returning `r.headers` instead of `r`?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is the redirect on success. This will throw another get request to same window. In your case this is not desired as you want to capitalize on the data from the form.

**views.py**

```
import requests

class IndexView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = CheckForm

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['headers'] = form.get_headers()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**forms.py**

```
import requests
from django import forms

class CheckForm(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=255, label='')

    def get_headers(self):
        if self.cleaned_data:
            url = self.cleaned_data['url']
            return requests.get(url).headers
        return {}
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="." method="post" name="url" id="url" novalidate>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Check</button>

{% if headers %}
{% for k,v in headers.items %}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<br>No data
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting `'CheckForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'` and apparently there is [no need to use get_context_data](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html) any more.

Comment: Good point, didn't know that one myself. Refined my answer as it was obviously wrong. Hope this helps bit more, work on my local at least.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort but I believe it's recommended to always use redirects after post requests so data won't be sent again when refreshing a page (I'll be storing results in database). It seems to be a simple task but I can't find solution do far...I was hoping to display results immediately without querying database but I may end up using two different views for this and pull data from database.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want to use `messages`

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

So now you can add some stuff and send it to the next template.

```
messages.success(request, u"Success message - text only")
```

In template :

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's going for.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar requirement and passed the custom context (here a processed file) and the original `form` instance in `form_valid()` to a `render` method instead of the forms default  `HttpResponseRedirect`.

```py
# forms.py

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

```py
# views.py

class MyFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'path/to/template/mytemplate.html'
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['processed_data'] = None
        return context

    def do_some_processing(self, file):
        # process file...
        return processed_data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form = super().form_valid(form)

        custom_context = {
            "form": self.form_class,
            "processed_data": self.do_some_processing(self.request.FILES['file']),
        }
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        context.update(custom_context)

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

```html
# mytemplate.html

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<pre>
{{ processed_data }}
</pre>
```